# Calculate row sum but exclude a column in R

Tags: r

I want to calculate the sum of the columns, but exclude one column.How can I specify what column to exclude while adding the sum of each row.

```
hd_total<-rowSums(hd) #hd is where the data is that is read is being held 
hn_total<-rowSums(hn)
```

Comment: `rowSums(hd[, -1])` (as an example) would remove the first column. Is that what you mean?

Comment: so if I were to change -1 to -2 it would remove the 2 column?

Comment: Yes. That's the basic idea. To remove multiple, use `c()`.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html) and at `?Extract`

Answer (score 17):

```
rowSums(hd[, -n])
```

where `n` is the column you want to exclude.

Comment: What If I need to exclude more than one column? Let's say: 1 and 5

Comment: just put those columns like this - rowSums(hd[, -c(n,n1,n2)])